# How do I store astronomically huge numbers into variables?

Tags: java

I'm still new to Java, and one of the ideas I had to make things more interesting is trying to make an algorithm that would convert numbers into letters (1000 = 1k // 1.000.000 = 1M // 1E+15 = 1aa..it would be an optimizer for a mobile game) , but turn out even double type variables has a pretty small limit compared to the numbers I want to work with (i.e 9.48E+3048).

Any ideas on how to approach this issue?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: You can use `java.math.BigDecimal` or `java.math.BigInteger` to store arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: Maybe you explain again what you exactly want to achieve. What is the point of putting thousands of zeros into a variable? Mesning: why is 9.48E3048 not good enough?

Comment: If `1E15` would be converted to `1aa` then what would `9.48E3048` look like? Also, what kind of game are you writing that's confronting players with numbers they can't grasp (I'm pretty sure that if they can't understand 9.48E3048 they will have difficulties with the size of the number anyway)?

Comment: The game itself is pretty simple, you have monsters that start with 10 HP(health bar) at level 1 and every level you go up, the next one has 33% more HP than the last. At the early stages, it's small numbers, but as soon as you keep going, they start to have huge HP's, that's where the gigantic numbers come from. What I intend to do is predict how much HP they have at certain stages and how much "damage" you need in order to kill him given 120 seconds (The game itself has 32000 stages and monsters at 10000 have ~3,284E+1238 HP).

Comment: And I'm not creating the game, it already exists. I'm just trying to create a calculator for personal use.

Comment: @GhostCat This is most likely for a cookie-clicker type game, where the game is designed to use unreasonable large exponents. It's a fairly common genre of webgames. (I can't @ Thomas in the same msg. Hmf)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. You might want to put some of that info into the question. It is not good practice to give such details via comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import java.math.BigInteger;
...
BigInteger myint = new BigInteger("5");
myint = myint.add(new BigInteger("7")); // 12`

BigIntegers are immutable (They can't change), so the process is simply to .add, .multiply, etc, to get new numbers, and then overwrite variables as shown above. They will hold arbitrarily large numbers. All other functionality can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

You will want to avoid converting integer to string as it will be too slow for numbers that large. Make a custom method to convert the most significant binary digits into the strings you desire (1k, 1M, 1aa, etc).

An alternative is hold two doubles in a (mantissa, exp) format, just as double does internally. After every operation, move the mantissa's exponent into the exponent variable with `exp = this.getExponent()`, `mantissa = this.getMantissa()`. `getExponent` could return something like `floor(log(mantissa)) + exp`, and `getMantissa` could return `mantissa / nextLowerPowerOfTen(mantissa)`. This will give you 10^(10^3048), with 15 digits accuracy in the mantissa and 15 digits accuracy in the exponent.